# displaying multiple templates in a single php Smarty file

Tags: php, smarty

Hello stackoverflow community!

I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem. I have a contact.php file which looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->caching        = false;
$smarty->debugging         = false;
$smarty->template_dir     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templates/';
$smarty->compile_dir      = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/smarty/templates_c';
$smarty->cache_dir        = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/smarty/cache';

$smarty->display('contact.tpl');

die;
```

in my contact.tpl file I have my form:

```
    {extends file="index.tpl"} 
    {block name="content"}
    my form....
    {/block}
```

And I include my block named content through a master file called index.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<main>
...
     {block name="content"}{/block}
</main>
```

THE PROBLEM:
Everything is working, however, in this case I would have to create a large number of php files (like contact.php) which are displaying the right template. How can I go about with a single php file, and get it to display the right template depending on what page link the user clicks on? E.g. when the user clicks on the contact page, I would like it to display contact.tpl, when the user clicks on the 'about' page, I would like it to display about.tpl without having a separate php file for each case.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking to just use an include :

Like below :

Your PHP display "contact.tpl":

```
$smarty->display('contact.tpl');
```

and into contact.tpl as example you need the index from another tpl.

Here is your contact.tpl :

```
{include file="index.tpl"}

{block name="content"}
   my form....
{/block}
```

This way you'll display both contact.tpl and index.tpl within the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use url parameters i.e. index.php?pag=contact, index.php?pag=home

and then in your index.php it's just a matter of using a switch

```
switch ($_GET['pag'])
{
   case 'contact':
      $template="contact.tpl";
      //you can also declare some variables for one particular view to use them in the template
      $data=array('my_mail'=>'test@test.com');
   break;

   case 'home':
      $template="home.tpl";
   break;

   default:
      $template="error404.tpl";
   break;

}

$smarty->assign(array('data'=>$data,'something_else'=>$more_data));
$smarty->display($template);
```

You can hide the parameters in the url using htaccess, so, mydomain.com/index.php?pag=contact can easily become mydomain.com/contact