# Smarty display functions: displaying multiple templates from single php file is not displaying all the templates

Tags: php

I have already seen this

[displaying multiple templates in a single php Smarty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460807/displaying-multiple-templates-in-a-single-php-smarty-file)

I am working on a client project...

In a php file there are two display smarty functions which displays two smarty templates.. which works fine in the production( online) server.. But not working in my local server.

In my system it displays only the first template..

Comment: Not related to Smarty in any way. Enable error reporting, check `php_errors.log`.

Comment: @axiac ok bro I will check it

Comment: @axiac thank you very much bro I have found the solution using php_errors.log. the problem was Fatar Error: Call to undefined function smarty_modifier_replace(). I just removed the cache . and it worked fine..again thank you bro